# I have a UITextField that gets hidden by the keyboard when selected. How can it be brought into view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITableView` that is shorter than the window, therefore it does not need to scroll. However, it *is* long enough that when a text field in the bottom row is selected, the keyboard covers it.

I can't use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` because the table is shorter than the window, so I was wondering what the correct way to bring it into view would be.

I was thinking about sliding the whole view up a set number of pixels, although that seems very bad form because it would break the UI if I added more rows to the table.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement these methods in the concerned class :

```
- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)myTextField
{
    [self animateTextField:myTextField up:YES];
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)myTextField
{
    [self animateTextField:myTextField up:NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    int movement = (up ? -105 : 105);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

You have to adapt values (`-105`, `105` and `0.3f`) to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the whole tableView slide up by setting the height of the footerView. The Keyboard will move the table above for the height of the footer

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 70.0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a nice way to do it, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Is it as simple as declaring the method in the implementation file of the class where I create the table?
Where do I pass in the section parameter?

Comment: Just add this to the .m file of the tableView you want to change :)

Answer (score 0):

Pierre's code worked for me, but I removed the myTextField argument. It seemed unnecessary. I also changed this over to UITextViews because that's what I had in my code. Otherwise, thanks for the question and answers. I've been beating my head against the wall to solve this problem!

```
#pragma mark - Text View Delegate

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self animateTextViewUp:YES];
}

- (void) textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [self animateTextViewUp:NO];
}

- (void) animateTextViewUp:(BOOL)up
{
    int movement = (up ? -80 :80);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```